# Weird updateViewLayout behaviour

Tags: android, layout

I have a view (custom drawn) added with `getWindowManager().addView()` and later I'm modifiying the `LayoutParameters` of it (changing `x` & `width`) and call `getWindowManager().updateViewLayout()`. This works but I am getting two screen refreshes, first one only moves the whole thing according to the new `x` and later one scales it according to the new width. Any ideas about why is this happening even though I only call `updateViewLayout` just one time with the new layout parameters?

FYI: `onDraw` method of the custom drawn view mentioned here is also called only one time by the system during this process.

Comment: Are onMeasure or onLayout called as expected ?

Comment: As @Snicolas stated, maybe one of the layout functions are causing this re-layout/measure or parent-invalidation

Comment: did you solve this issue? using runOnUiThread only made is worse somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          view.updateViewLayout();
       }
    });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

If it doesn't work, check this:

[How to move a view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415306/whats-the-best-way-to-move-a-view-in-android)

Are you doing this?

Answer (score 2):

try to do :

```
view.post(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    view.updateViewLayout();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`updateViewLayout` is an a method that can be overriden by your custom `ViewGroup` and in this overrided method you can implement all what your want to change.

Maybe you do something wrong in it?

Or also maybe you have to implement this code in `UiThread` like in other questions. - In this case when you change your parameters asynchronously with first call of drawing function by system you method maybe can change only one parameter and on second call the second parameter will be also changed.