# Hide view when draggin up

Tags: android

I have a layout with 2 LinearLayout. The first one is used as a container to contain a graph, and the second one contains few buttons.

[image: 1]

When the app starts, at first instance the LinearLayout1 which contains the graph is hidden `View.GONE`.

[image: 2]

Then when I touch a button from LinearLayout2, this layout goes back to its original place using a translate animation.

[image: 3]

Finally, I should have the capability to hide again the LinearLayout1. I would like to achieve this by draggin up the LinearLayout2, so when the user has moved a bit upwards the LinearLayout2, the LinearLayouy1 would become again hidden by `View.GONE`.

[image: 4]

This final part is the one with I need some help. I have tried something using an `OnTochListener()` but I haven't worked too much with this and i'm not sure about how to do it. This is code snnipet where I do this:

```
/*Layout views*/
private View graphContainer;  //This is the LinearLayout1
private View valuesContainer; //This is the LinearLayout2
private float oldY;
private float newY;

...

valuesContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                float y = event.getY();
                oldY = y;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float y2 = event.getRawY();
                newY = y2;
                if (oldY < newY) {
                    graphContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
         }
         return true;
    }
});
```

Depending on where I touch to do the movement I get to set the visibility to GONE, but the movement is not as I would like, I don't get to move the LinearLayout2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did above is hiding layout2 when the user moves it's finger up.

You say that "you don't get to move the LinearLayout2" -> in order to move a view you need to update it's LayoutParams. You can see an example to this here : [How to move a view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415306/whats-the-best-way-to-move-a-view-in-android)

This way you can "push" layout2 up and at some point hide layout1 (using animation, or pushing layout1 as well). Hope this helps.

**Edit** (a requested code sample) :

BTW - [animations transitions](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html) is the better way to go when view's params needs changing. It's not the answer to your question since you want a real "drag" feel (when going up).
Also - [android L has some beautiful animations](https://developer.android.com/preview/samples.html) (I haven't used yet) that we should keep an eye on.

So... using a layout as follows :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and a corresponding activity as follows :

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    int yDown = 0;
    int initialTopMargin = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_layout);

        layout2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        params.topMargin = initialTopMargin - (yDown - (int)event.getRawY());
                        view.setLayoutParams(params);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        yDown = (int)event.getRawY();
                        initialTopMargin = params.topMargin;
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I didn't know exactly how to say it but you did it, what I really need is to push layout 2 up and at some point hide layout1 setting it's visibility to GONE. If you can provide an example to this, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Edited. Note that I don't actually hide layout1 (which is possible) nor do I push it up (also possible) - but that should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

how about using [onDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html) ?

```
    valuesContainer.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                float y = event.getY();
                oldY = y;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float y2 = event.getRawY();
                newY = y2;
                if (oldY < newY) {
                    graphContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
         }
         return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I changed my method with yours but the Linearlayout2 isn't moving neither the linearLayout1 get's GONE